# Creating a xmlDoc using libxml2

Tags: c++, libxml2

Can anyone help me with how to create an xmlDoc using libxml2?
I have a function:

```
xmlDocPtr createDocument()
{
   xmlDocPtr document;
   document = xmlNewDoc((const xmlChar*)"1.0"); // XML version


   return document;
}
```

The xml document should have the follow content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
<rootNamespace::node xmlns:xsi="http://link1" xmlns:ism="abc" xmlns:rootNamespace="http://link2">
    <security ism:classification:"U" ism:ownerProducer="ABC" ism:releasableTo="ABC" />
    <one>message 1</one>
    ....
</rootNamespace::node>
```

Thanks for your help,

ABS

Answer (score 0):

You could just take a look at libxml2's examples :

http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/tree2.c